# Can I use a modern Android phone with no phone plan?

Tags: wi-fi, data-plan

I'm new to the Android platform, but am looking into doing some development for Android 2.x, with the hope of publishing an app to the Android App Market eventually.  I'd like to be able to test my app on "real" hardware, but I already have an iPhone, which is plenty expensive itself, and I don't want to pay for an entire second cell phone plan just to test my code.  So my question is, is it possible to buy an unlocked Android phone and operate it entirely over wi-fi?  If so, what features (besides the obvious, like making calls), will I be missing out on?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it is possible, but it might be tricky depending on the phone.

For instance, I bought a T-Mobile G1 (not the Android Dev Phone version) and had to have a SIM card in it.  You can either borrow a friend's or you can do what I did, which was buy a prepaid-SIM card.  It cost less than $40.  If you have a friend's SIM card that has a data plan, then you can activate the phone.  But if you don't want to have to have a SIM card in the phone anymore, you'll have to root the phone and [install CyanogenMod](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Full_Update_Guide_-_HTC_Dream) on it.

Now if you bought a pre-paid SIM card, then you can activate the phone over wifi by following [these steps](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=G1_logon_to_google_via_wifi) (this is specific to the G1).

A G1 is probably the cheapest phone you can get if you're only wanting to use it as a hardware testing device. On ebay it is around the $100-150 range.

Comment: Great idea about the prepaid SIM card. I never thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: Actually as far as I know, you don't need a SIM at all. I mean I activated my Nexus One via wifi, and just booted it without a SIM as a test, and everything (except calling, obviously) works fine!

Comment: @kkaploon I had a T-Mobile branded G1.  It had to have a SIM card to get beyond the "SIM card required" screen.  If it was the ADP version of the G1, then this wouldn't have been a problem.

Comment: I would -1 the idea of getting a G1 itself. That device is ancient now and doesn't run the latest versions of Android due to lack of hardware capability. You can shoehorn some later versions on it, but it's slow. I would suggest if you still want to try and save money, go for a Samsung Galaxy S phone. They are easily rooted and make great wifi "iPod Touch with Android" type of device. Less than $200 on Ebay as of December 2011.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you download and install the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)?

The SDK contains an emulator that can simulate pretty much every aspect of the device.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  That's how I plan to do most of my development--I just want to test my app on real hardware before releasing it.

Answer (score 3):

My Android Hero needed a SIM card to start up.
However a 10$ prepaid SIM card will do.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, a pay-as-you-go SIM is a good solution for any phone. In the UK at least, you can pick up a free SIM card easily.  Vodafone or O2 will send you one if you ask them or you can probably get one at any number of local shops.  Just be aware that some handsets are locked to particular networks, so you will either need to get a SIM from that network or pay to have your phone unlocked.

However, some phones will work fine without a SIM.  I use an HTC Legend for development without a SIM and there is no problem.  I just use Wi-Fi and, since it can't make calls, it is effectively just a pocket computer.

Answer (score 2):

I bought a new unlocked Nexus One when they were available to the general public and it was perfectly willing to start up and use wifi without having a SIM. That's probably an expensive option, though.

Answer (score 1):

Prepaid is the way to go. You can purchase a T-Mobile [prepaid phone for $20-$30](http://www.t-mobile.com/shop/phones/prepaid.aspx), sometimes they even throw in a free $25 refill card. The phone comes with a free SIM card with $3 worth of air time (10 minutes). You need to refill your prepaid phone every 90 days for at least $10 each time, or if you want to avoid the hassle, you can refill $100 which is good for a year and achieve the gold status, thereafter any amount you refill will be good for up to a year. If you already own a T-Mobile phone, you might be able to just spend $7 on the prepaid site to purchase a *T-Mobile Prepaid SIM Card Activation Kit*.

The [CallingMart thread](http://www.fatwallet.com/forums/hot-deals/788826/) and [ePhoneCard thread](http://www.fatwallet.com/forums/hot-deals/891270/) on Fatwallet tells you how to buy cheap refill cards with coupon codes.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There do exist phones that aren't even capable of accepting a SIM card.  Phones meant to be used on Sprint and Verizon networks typically don't even have GSM capabilities.  They'll start up just fine without one (obviously).  For example, my HTC Evo doesn't have a SIM card slot -- this would be an expensive option though, I'm sure you could find cheaper phones.

Answer (score 0):

The [HTC Magic](http://www.htc.com/www/product/magic/overview.html) "Vodafone edition" at least requires a SIM card, even if it has been unlocked to use any operator. If there is no SIM present then a modal dialog (that cannot be closed) is shown that requests you to insert a SIM card.

**Update**: The SIM is only required to fill in the Google Account details (even if you do this over Wifi, as I did). Once the phone is "activated" in this way, you can run it SIM-free.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do quite a bit on my phone before the activation was completed using wifi. There are some things you might not be able to test, such as app behavior after/during a call interruption, however, for the most part, the functionality available using wifi mode is sufficient. You can test call interruption type of behaviors using the android emulator.

You may also want to note that many cell phone companies, including but not limited to att, have significantly cheaper rarely-advertised "data only" plans, should you discover you really do need to do testing using a real cell-phone network (eg: if you made a multi-media app, testing over wifi might perform differently than over the air). Pre-paid plans sometimes also include data-plan airtime as another option to consider, if needed.

Comment: Jessica Brown - Any advice on how one would find info/carriers that offer these "data only" plans?

Comment: Call the carriers customer service numbers and ask whether they have such a plan. Or search google for related terms. Here's one I found for T-mobile: http://www.t-mobile.com/shop/plans/cell-phone-plans.aspx?catgroup=mobilebroadband it appears verizon has something similar aimed as a plan for tablet users: http://www.verizonwireless.com/wcms/consumer/shop/prepaid.html