# Using a phone without data plan for multiplayer game dev

Tags: wi-fi

I would like to try out android programming and specifically try my hand at some multiplayer development, but I no longer have an active phone plan for my android phone.  Is it possible to just use wi-fi without having a 3g data plan?  There is no need to make calls, only access my wireless network.

[Edit] The phone is a Galaxy S Mesmerize if that helps.  I'm at work, so I can't take a look at the phone to see if it needs a SIM card.  It was from US Cellular so I don't think it needs one.  Not sure tho.

Comment: [Can I use a modern Android phone with no phone plan?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/701)

Comment: @eldareathis I think that's the right idea but my answer there is so old (a G1!!!).

Comment: To the op: if you have a phone that requires a SIM card, you will most likely need to flash a custom rom like CyanogenMod so you don't always have to have a SIM card plugged in. Otherwise... you should just be able to use a phone as is, unactivated.

Comment: I don't know about GSM models, but my Verizon Galaxy Nexus works fine without its SIM card.

Comment: @Wyzard the SIM card on a GN is only for 4G (I have one too)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the model/carrier - your unit could block the access to the UI (past the "Emergency calls only" screen) without being activated. If you can root the unit - this can be easily bypassed.